# Not able to throw custom Exception in Platform specific code, and catch in shared code

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a custom Exception class and I am trying to throw that from my Platform specific implementation in .NET MAUI. And I want to catch that exception in my MainPage.xaml.cs, where the object is initialized.

```cs
// Exception class
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
    public MyCustomException(string message) : base(message) { }
}

// MyClass partial class in MainCode/Common code
public partial class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        try
        {
            MyPrivateMethod();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MyCustomException("Error initializing MyClass");
   
        }
    }

    partial void MyPrivateMethod();

    partial void MyCalledMethod();
}

// Platform-specific implementation of MyClass partial class for .NET MAUI
public partial class MyClass
{
    partial void MyPrivateMethod()
    {
        MyCalledMethod(); // Call the platform-specific implementation of MyCalledMethod
    }

    partial void MyCalledMethod()
    {
        // Implement the platform-specific code for MyCalledMethod
        // This method can throw an exception
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong in MyCalledMethod");
    }
}

// Usage in MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            _myClass = new MyClass();
        }
        catch (MyCustomException ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception here
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I get Exception Unhandled error at the MyCalledMethod in Platform Specific code. I want to handle MyCustomException in MainPage.xaml.cs and work accordingly.

Comment: Does the unhandled Exception crash the app? Or are you able to "Continue" from it in the Debugger? I've seen situations (not related to "partial") where debugging Android paused at an exception, but then Continue did what was expected (went to the "catch" block). That is, for some reason "Pause only if Not Handled" acts like "Pause when Exception Thrown", when debugging Android.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i am running this on android. But continue doesnt work. After 2 clicks of continue. It crashes the app and gives fatal: exception not handled.

Comment: I made a demo using the same code in your question. Strangely, it doesn't crash and can ```Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");``` in the MainPage.xaml.cs.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT strange. can you tell which platform did you run your code on. and your .net version.

Comment: In VS Community 17.6.0, works for me on both Windows and Android, when add your code to a default Maui project. (You don't show namespaces, but since it reached your `throw` line, I assume the platform-specific partial code for MyClass is in the `same namespace as the  common code`, not in a namespace such as `MyAppName.Droid`.) Make a `public github repo` with just enough code to build and run, to show this bug. I recommend starting over and `adding your code to a new Maui project`. If that works, then its a matter of finding what is different in your original.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, finally was able to solve it. I was using an async method before and didn't rebuild the solution after removing it. Removing the bin folder and rebuilding the whole solution again, solved it.

Answer (score 0):

First try to fix the MyCustomException constructor I see that you are using two parameters and there is just defined one.
Fix:

```
public MyCustomException(string message, Exception ex) : base(message, ex) { }
```

Comment: Oh sorry thats a typo in sample code. I am just passing one param in exception and thats the message